# Authenticate WordPress Site through another WordPress installation?

Tags: multisite, authentication

We have two different WordPress websites for our clients. Both have different content that need to be on separate installations. One installation already has all of our users since it existed well before our new site. Is it possible to authenticate the new site through the old one?

I've seen plugins like this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-db-auth-reloaded/

But that is for an external Non-WordPress database, so none of their information will carry over.

Comment: Well Tom, its hard to do if they are seperate wp installation,  but if you make them into one wp multisite then I think you can custom code it somehow. But not possible for separate wp installation.

Answer (score 0):

Hook into [wp_login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) and use oAuth from the rest-api to validate against the other site.  I'm sure keeping the user info the same between the two sites would be tough though